# JSON API Rails 6 with Devise - SignUp Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, doorkeeper, warden

When i try to use the sign_up method of Devise, i get an internal server error but, after create the user.

My application.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.json? }
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  respond_to :json

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [ :username ])
  end
end
```

#### Here the output,

[image: rails s output]

Any ideas? 
I am supplementing this with Doorkeeper, but please do not alter the operation of Devise. I also did not use Warden on my own anywhere on the app.

---

Comment: Do you have a RegistrationsController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be the problem you are having:

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4603

They suggest clearing the cookies of your browser

> this usually happens when you are upgrading a bunch of stuck including
>   devise in one branch And than you get back to some other branch for
>   something and you have this newer cookie in your browser. Simple
>   solution is to clear cookies in browser.

Other answers mention upgrading devise version